unable to install kaleido
I am working on dash app. I have a plotly graph which I am trying to save as image. On running I got first error as
Image export using the ""kaleido"" engine requires the kaleido package,
which can be installed using pip:
    $ pip install -U kaleido

While trying to install it, I am getting this error as
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/demo_project$ poetry add kaleido
Using version ^0.2.1.post1 for kaleido

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing kaleido (0.2.1.post1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for kaleido (0.2.1.post1)

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:74 in choose_for
       70│ 
       71│             links.append(link)
       72│ 
       73│         if not links:
    →  74│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       75│ 
       76│         # Get the best link
       77│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       78│ 

Cannot install kaleido.

Please help.


Duplicate of this.
